# Group in regular expression of find command not working

Tags: regex, shell, command-line

I wanted to find all files with the extension .png and .jpg in a directory, but as soon as I try to search for two extension with the group matcher from regular expression it doesn't find anything.

Does the command "find" not support groups, or am I using them wrong. I used https://regex101.com/ to test the expression below and it gave me the result I expected.

I tried the command `find ./assets -regex '.*\.(png|jpg)'` but this doesn't show any files.

If I use

```
find ./assets -regex '.*\.png'
find ./assets -regex '.*\.jpg'
```

it finds all files I search for, but I need it in one command.

I also, just for test purpose, tried `find ./assets -regex '.*\.(.*)'` which also finds not a single file. And adding `-regextype posix-extended` gives an error.

It should match for example:

```
./assets/image.png
./assets/subdir/image2.png
./assets/image3.jpg
```

There are some JSON files as well which should not be matched, like:

```
./assets/image.json
./assets/subdir/image2.json
```

Don't know if this is relevant or not but I'm on a MacBook and use the zsh terminal.

Comment: You may want to try this: find -E ./assets -regex '.*\.(png|jpg)' on a Mac. You need to specify option `-E`, which tells command `find` to interpret regex as extended (modern) regex rather than basic one.

Comment: Thanks @DenisRasulev this works perfect. I read about the -E option in the man page but put it after the path which gave an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first comment says I missed the -E option to use extended (modern) regex.

```
find -E ./assets -regex '.*\.(png|jpg)'
```